# Why aren't my Wordpress menu items showing the pages to which they link?

Tags: hyperlink, menu

I'm adding a custom menu, using this code to register the menu:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_custom_menu' );
function register_custom_menu() {
    register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Main Menu' ) );
    }
```

And this code to display the menu:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
    'container_class' => 'header-menu',
    )   );
?>
```

The Problem:

The menu is registered.  I can create it.  I can save it.  It displays on the web page.

It does not display the page to which it is linked.  The address bar will show, for example, "http://localhost:8888/sample-page/" but it isn't displaying that page, it stays on the home page.

There are no error messages.

Where do I start to look for the problem?

Comment: You are not saying/showing anything about the NavWalker in your header.php file. That is the instance, which will "walk" through your nav_menu and display the items. Wrong Walker = wrong output. Additionally, please add a note that this question is about WordPress. One has to guess.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't think I'm creating a Walker menu, but I'll check.  The problem isn't displaying the menu, the problem is it doesn't work, but every hint helps.  I cannot add "Wordpress" to the subject line.  I tried, it kept throwing back an error message.  Perhaps, like trying to use "Custom" in the subject line,  I don't have enough points to be allowed to use it.

Comment: Aha!  I was allowed to add "Wordpress" through an edit.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: In case you didn't know, there is an entire Stackpage for WordPress. See, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com - so, your question would be more appropriate there. More views, more help etc.